# Disney princess cross overs in Sofia the First

Tags: disney, sofia-the-first

So far *Sofia the First* has featured many [Disney princesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofia_the_First#Disney_Princesses) and associated characters<sup>1</sup>. Does this mean that all Disney princesses are part of the same world, is there some sort of magic portal between Enchancia and the worlds of the other princesses, or is this some sort of altered universe that happens to contain the other princesses?

---

1: [Most recently Olaf](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-3397984/Olaf-snowman-appear-Sofia-Frozen-finally-debuts-Disney-Channel.html).

Comment: Maybe the background of the overspanning [Disney Princess Franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney_Princess) provides some insight on the matter, specifically statements like *"This was the first time the characters would be marketed in a separate franchise than their original films. Mooney decided that, when featured on marketing advertisements such as posters, the princesses should never make eye contact with each other in an attempt to keep their individual "mythologies" intact. "[Each] stares off in a slightly different direction as if unaware of the others' presence.""*

Comment: While not canon, the videogame Kingdom Hearts did a very good job of combining a good portion of Disney tales into one story, and several Princesses lived in the same "universe".  So, this isn't a new concept when it comes to Disney.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The princesses are summoned magically ***through time & space*** by the [Amulet of Avalor](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Amulet_of_Avalor):

> The wearer's good deeds bestow magical abilities; whereas bad deeds cause the wearer to be cursed. Also, according to Cinderella, the Amulet connects all of the princesses that ever existed.
>
> Princess Summoning: When the one wearing the Amulet really needs help, the Amulet summons Disney Princesses to help them out.
>
> It can summon Princesses from the past, according to Cinderella, **"all princesses that ever lived."** Interestingly, it seems to be implied by Tiana's appearance that princesses from the future can also be summoned.

This is explained in the very first episode by Cinderella.

Comment: So all of the Disney princesses have lived on the same planet but might not be alive at the same time, and these are the same true princesses as discovered in their original movies.

Comment: @Erik if you want them alive at the same time, then you want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descendants_(2015_film)

Comment: lol I don't care if they're all alive at the same time I was just making sure I understood your answer.

Comment: @erik yes. In Sofia the First, all the princesses are actual people in history/future, not storybook fairy tales. Well, they are fairy tales, but, you know, factual.